# Big O notation of the following min and max recursive code in Java

Tags: java, big-o

So `n` is the length of array a and p is an array of `int` of len 2.both elements are zero in  p. The first call is `findbigO(a, n-1, p)`.

```java
findbigO(int[] a, int i, int[] p)
if (i == 0) {
   p[0] = a[0];
   p[1] = a[0];
} else {
   findbigO(a, i‐1, p);
   if (a[i] < p[0]]) {
      p[0] = a[i];
   }
   if (a[i] > p[1]]) {
      p[1] = a[i];
   }
}
```

The code basically finds the max and min in an array and stores them in an different array P. I am trying to figure out the Big O of this code. i think its Big O of n since recursion is called n times depending on the length of the array. what do you guys think

Comment: That seems right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `i` in the first call is by definition `n-1`, i.e. of the same magnitude as `n`. Thus, for big-O-over-`n` notation purposes, the initial `i` can be treated as `n`.

The code itself is, other than the recursive invocation, constant time: There are no fors or whiles or any other way in which this code's # of executions is affected by anything.

The recursive call neccessarily marches towards the end condition (i == 0, when no recursion occurs), and does so in O(n) time: In fact, after exactly `n` steps, 0 will have been reached.

Thus, we have an O(1) 'loop' being executed `O(i-initial)` times, where `i-initial` is the same magnitude as `n`, which combines to `O(1) * O(n)` which is just `O(n)`.

To help you out and to confirm big O notation, here's the 'point' of big-O:

Make a 2D line graph. On the x-axis, put 'n'. On the y-axis, put 'time taken by the CPU'.

Then fill in this chart. It'll be messy at first (maybe in one of the runs, your winamp switches songs or whatnot), but go far enough to the right and the algorithmic complexity of the input will start being the deciding factor. It 'balances out', in other words, into a recognizable graph. What does that graph look like?

For this algorithm, a straight line, that is not horizontal. In other words, it looks like `y = C*x` with C being some constant. That's what `O(n)` means: That graph will eventually stabilize and look like `y = C*x` does, for some C.

`O(n^2)` would mean: The graph eventually stabilizes into something that looks like `y = x^2`. That's also why `O(x^2 + x)` is not a thing, because `y = x^2 + x`, once you go far enough to the right, looks like just `y = x^2` does on its right flank.

Answer (score 0):

findbigO(n) = findbigO(n-1) + (1)

findbigO(n) = (findbigO(n-2) + O(1)) + (1)

...

findbigO(n) = findbigO(n-n) + n*O(1)

findbigO(n) = findbigO(0) + n*O(1)

findbigO(n) = O(1) + n*O(1)

findbigO(n) = O(1) + n*O(1)

findbigO(n) = O(1) + O(n)

findbigO(n) <= O(n) + O(n)

findbigO(n) <= 2*O(n)

findbigO in O(n)